# Font size incorrect on mobile view

Tags: css

There is something I don't understand happening with the mobile view, on Mozilla and Chrome. I have a very simple setup : a p with some content in it, and a stylesheet in which I put a font-size of 20px on the body.

```css
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="vieport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <p>I am supposed to have a font-size of 20px, ain't I ?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, in desktop mode, no issue whatsoever, the font appears at the correct size. But whenever I switch to the mobile view, with a specific device selected (i.e. iPhone SE), the font doesn't display at the correct size. And if I happen to resize this window, while still being in mobile view, the font is immediately sized to its defined size. 
I've been trying to figure out what's going on but haven't found anything. I'd be grateful for an explanation about what's happening ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without a [mcve] of your css and html it is not possible to tell.

Comment: did you add a correct viewport meta tag?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[spelling error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOfwz.png)

try fixing this spelling error "viewport" in your meta tag

Comment: Ooooh thank you so much. You were the second pair of eyes I definetly needed today.